# Angular Material forms validation error message won't go away

Tags: forms, angular, angular-material2

I have a material form in which I have an `MdInput`:

```
<md-form-field class="input-full-width">
    <input mdInput class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Description" formControlName="periodDesc">
    <md-error *ngIf="fb.get('periodDesc').errors.required">This field is required</md-error>
</md-form-field>
```

The validate message appears when the field has been touched but no text has been typed in. However, the validate message persists even when I try to type in text there:

[image]

**Edit 1:**

The issue gets fixed when I do this instead:

```
<md-error *ngIf="fb.hasError('required', ['periodDesc'])">This field is required</md-error>
```

However, my question is why did the issue occur in the first place? Is there anything wrong with the previous case because I am using it in other places where the second one won't work. Ref: [Angular Material forms validation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46174960/angular-material-forms-validation-errors)

Comment: I have stated the reason at my answer. See the first paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that When a formControl has no validator errors(see **[here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L127)**), `fb.get('periodDesc').errors` will return *null*. So your current way will throw `null error` like `can not find required of null`.

Use `fb.get('periodDesc').hasError('required')` instead of `fb.get('periodDesc').errors.required` to prevent from above error.